# How to analyse the space usage inside a pdf in linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, compression

I often have to shrink pdf size, while keeping most of the quality. My main problem is understanding the relative size taken by the different objects, (fonts, text, images,...) inside the pdf, so that I can apply the right, selective compression strategy.

Is there any open source tool on a linux base operating system to get those informations ? I haven't found any answer yet.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can actually open a PDF file in a text editor, and see for yourself how much space the various objects take. A PDF consists of a number of objects (e.g. fonts, images, commands to describe a page, ...), and often the content of the objects is compressed. You can uncompress those with `mutool clean -d ...`. The package `mupdf-tools` on Debian contains `mutool`.

I can already tell you that in most cases, images will take up most of the space, followed by fonts. So reducing the number of fonts, and rendering the images in a lower resolution will give you most space gains.